# 3d to 2d image transformation - PointCloud to OpenCV Image - C++

Tags: c++, opencv, 3d, 2d, point-cloud-library

I'm collecting a hand 3d image from my Kinect, and I want to generate a 2d image using only the X and Y values to do image processing using OpenCV. The size of the 3d matrix is variable and depends on the output from the Kinect and the X and Y values are not in proper scale to generate an 2d image. My 3d points and my 3d image are: http://postimg.org/image/g0hm3y06n/

[image]

I really don't know how can I generate my 2d image to perform my Image Processing.

Someone can help me or have a good example that I can use to create my image and do the proper scaling for that problem? I want as output the HAND CONTOURS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should apply Delaunay triangulation to 2D coordinates of point cloud (depth ignored), then remove too long vertices from triangles. You can estimate the length threshold by counting points per some area and evaluating square root from the value you'll get. After you got triangulation you can draw filled triangles and find contours.

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for the answer. The contours that I will find will be 3d points? Actually, a simpler approach that I want, is create a Mat, jpg or other kind of image that I can perform Image Processing using OpenCV for gesture recognition. Do you know how can I do this transformation?

Comment: You can get binary image using morphology operators. You can apply cv::dilate with kernel size a little bit larger than average distance between points on the image. This will make points become larger and you'll get solid hand silhouette. Then you can apply erosion to reduce the silhouette to initial size. This operation is named closing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_(morphology)

Comment: Hi Andrey, this will work fine to me, but I have a basic problem, because to do the Erosion and Dilatation I need to create a image that I can read with OpenCV imread. Now I have just the PCD (Point Cloud File), I already did a projection, so just my X and Y components are different from 0. Do you know how can I get my PCD file and create a file that I can read with imread? Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to do the follwing steps: 1) Measure point set dimensions (use boundingRect http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=boundingrect#boundingrect ). 2) Scale you point set to convenient size (say with width 512px). 3) Offset pointset's upper left corner to image origin. 4) Draw points (you can use direct write to memory or cv::rectangle for instance) 5) Apply morphology. 6) Find contours.       In case of using drawing primitives (rectangles or circles) dilation operator may not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [OKPCL package](https://github.com/Qworg/OKPCL).. Also, make sure you check out [this PCL post](http://www.pcl-users.org/Conversion-from-cv-Mat-to-pcl-PointCloud-td4023936.html) about the topic.. There is also an [OpenCVPCL Bridge](http://kforge.ros.org/) class but apparently the website is down.

And lastly, there has been [official word](http://pointclouds.org/news/2011/05/03/opencv-pcl/) that the OpenCV and PCL are joining forces for a development platform that integrates GPU computing with 2d/3D perception and processing.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You could use PCLs [RangeImage](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_range_image.html) respectively [RangeImagePlanar](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_range_image_planar.html) class with its [createFromPointCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1_range_image.html#a82f6a143de2d73a0ad9fea6c527a2efb) method (I think you do have a point cloud, right? Or what do you mean by 3D image?).

Then you can create a OpenCV Mat using `getImagePoint` functions.